# Search and Shared Service Provider (SSP)

Tags: search, shared-service-provider

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise.

I am new and learning Shared Service Provider (SSP), which is a new concept in SharePoint Server 2007. I am creating publishing portal template web applications.

I want to know what is the relationship between Search service (the search box on the top right corner of default.aspx of a publishing portal template web site) and SSP? Search service itself is a SSP? Or Search service is a part of SSP? Or some other relationships?

Answer (score 2):

I thought this was answered yesterday.

Here are two additional links from a web search:

- What is a SSP?  - http://msmvps.com/blogs/shane/archive/2007/06/29/what-is-a-shared-service-provider.aspx
- Plan SSPs - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263276.aspx

While Shane's post look pretty close to what I said, there is a bit more detail to it.  The simple answer is that your publishing site calls a query tool that is provided data gathered in the index maintained by the SSP.

Comment: Can I understand relationship between SSP and search like this -- SSP is a set of shared service, and one of such shared service is search. All of such shared service (i.e. SSP) are hosted on one web application?

Answer (score 1):

The Search Service in MOSS is part of the Shared Services Provider.  SSP is a set of services that can be shared across multiple farms.  So when you associate a web application with an SSP, that web application will use that ssp for search, user profiles, my sites, excel services, bdc, audiences, etc.

Comment: Can I understand relationship between SSP and search like this -- SSP is a set of shared service, and one of such shared service is search. All of such shared service (i.e. SSP) are hosted on one web application?

Comment: Yes but I wouldn't really say that the SSP is hosted on one web application, I would say the website for administrating the SSP is hosted on a web application.